# Watchers of the Word Wall

Tags: word, knowledge, connect-wall

The guards group near the campfire. None of them wants to leave the warm flames, yet someone has to go to make the patrol along the border.
Of course, in this situation, the youngest of them is the one that must do the duty. He picks up a torch and leaves the others behind.

Nearly a half league away he finds something strange: as his torch casts light on the wall, seemingly random words appear in front of his eyes:

```
Silk            Origami     Bug track       King

Colored crown   Cross       Piety           Barbary

Avengers        Widow       Construction    Cannibalism

Feather         Apex        Red Lily        Circus
```

He has no idea what this could mean, but he is determined to not go back to the elders without a theory: who could have left these marks and what are they saying?

**What are the four categories hidden in these words and *who is the guard?***

*(The rules of a standard connect wall apply: you have to find 4 categories, each containing 4 connected word. The 4 categories are also connected, and help you find the final answer.)*

Comment: just want to confirm that 'Avangers' is not supposed to be 'Avengers'

Comment: Thanks, it was supposed to be - I always make this mistake in it's spelling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partial answer that could be far from correct:

> **MANTIS**:
> bug track ([Mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis_Bug_Tracker) is a bug tracking software)
> avengers ([Mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis_(Marvel_Comics)) is a member of the Avengers)
> cannibalism (the [praying mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praying_mantis) eats the head of the male after intercourse)
> piety ([piety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piety) is religious devotion, often exhibited through praying)
> **CRANE**
> origami (cranes are one of the most popular [origami designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orizuru))
> feather ([cranes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_(bird)) are birds with feathers)
> colored crown (they can have colored crowns, such as the [red-crowned crane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-crowned_crane))
> construction (a [crane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_(machine)) is also a piece of machinery used for construction)
> **LION**
> king (as in [The Lion King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion_King))
> barbary (the [barbary lion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbary_lion) is an extinct species)
> circus (many circuses feature lions)
> apex (lions are [apex predators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_predator))
> **SPIDER**
> widow ([black widows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_widow_spider) are spiders)
> red lily (the [red spider lily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycoris_radiata) is a species of lily)
> silk (spiders build their webs with [silk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_silk))
> cross ([cross spiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araneus_diadematus) apparently exist).
> This leads me to clans in [Legend of the Five Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Five_Rings). The wall in question would be the [Kaiu Kabe](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Kaiu_Kabe), making the guard a member of the [Crab Clan](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Crab_Clan).

Comment: All 3 categories are correct! It won't be hard to find the 4th from here :)

Comment: Everything is correct - to be able to identify the guards, just read a little about the "Wall" in the game, and you will find the 5th category, and get the well-deserved tick.